# How to enable the incoming e-mail in a document library within a SharePoint APP?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-addin

Is that possible? I don't see the Library Settings button on the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

According to the thread [Sharepoint mail enabled libraries](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/809/2362.aspx#2362):

> This functionality is currently **disabled** due to the performance
>   concerns, as well as security, data requirement, legal compliance and
>   scalability concerns.

Comment: If it's disabled: Why can I browse to the "/_layouts/EmailSettings.aspx" page?